# Angular @HostListener event triggered multiple times

Tags: angular, events, ionic3

I'm building an Ionic 3 app, where I have made an "auto-complete" directive, which is a simple directive that
pops up an auto-complete dialog when the element gets focus. This is done in "auto-complete" via:

```
@HostListener('ionFocus', ['$event._native.nativeElement'])
  onFocus(target) {
      target.blur();
      this.showAutocompleteDialog(target);
  }
```

This worked when I only used the directive in pages that were only used once in the system.

But then I made a new component, let's call it "AddressField", which has a "auto-complete" directive in one of the elements in its template. 
Now the @HostListener onFocus event gets triggered twice and hence two autocomplete dialogs are shown.

This only happens for the "auto-complete" directives within the AddressField components, and it only triggers twice for the second instance
of "AddressField" in the system.

Am I somehow using the @HostListener in a wrong way, or does this sound like a bug that should be filed? In either case, a workaround of some sort would
be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just an update on this:

In the end, it's my impression that this comes down to a bug in angular (see fx https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/issues/86) - at least, I wasn't able to find any problems with my approach.

My solution was a hacky one: I added a flag "alreadyFired" to my directive, checking for that in my HostListener function.

```
@HostListener('ionFocus', ['$event._native.nativeElement'])
  onFocus(target) {
    if (this.alreadyFired) {
      return;
    }
    this.alreadyFired = true;
    target.blur();
    this.showAutocompleteDialog(target);
}
```

And then of course when dismissing the dialog, I again set the alreadyFired flag to false again. Hacky, but working under a deadline..

Answer (score -1):

I had a very similar problem where I had two instances of the same component. Therefore there were two EventListeners.

**Note:** It is important that these EventListeners also get closed again to prevent memory leaks. This can be done for instance in the ngOnDestroy() hook.
The solution to this was adding the EventListener the oldschool way like this:

```
if (!condition) {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
            //do something
        });
    }
```

In one of the components I set an attribute so the condition would apply. This was done by an

```
@Input()
condition = false;
```

and in one of the html elements

```
[condition]="true"
```

In the end only one of the components fired the event.

Comment: addEventListener is a vanilla JS function which remains open after it's used which can lead into memory leak if it's not closed properly. Angular HostListener takes care of this issue. Also I don't think we can use @input variables in html tags. It's designed for <my-component [condition]="true"> .